What is the "LBGT+ Commitment Charter" that Paris 2024 signed back in July 2018?
According to the Olympics official page:

As an employer, Paris 2024 signed the LBGT+ Commitment Charter in July 2018 [..]


[..] the creation of a Pride House is in line with the commitments made by Paris 2024 and our various stakeholders in this area [..]

What is the specific charter signed back then?
In the EU Commission site I see that there are Diversity charters by EU country.
The corresponding charter for France is here, but I don't see "Paris 2024" or "Paris Organising Committee for the 2024 Olympic and Paralympic Games" among the signatories.
Is the mentioned signed charter somewhere publicly available?

This appears to be a factual question about a commitment made by a private organization, not a question about politics.

Even with all the translation approximations "Diversity Charter" would probably not be translated as "LBGT+ Commitment". So probably it's a different one. Also, I removed the European Commision tag since I don't see how it applies.

@Jen I don't know if the Olympics is conducted by a private organisation, but doesn't international treaties and diplomacy come in play with the Olympics? If so, this Q should be allowed here.

@sfxedit it is a private organization. However, yes, some questions relating to the Olympics might also happen to be about government, processes, policy within the scope of this site. Those would be on topic. This one is not one of those. This is asking about a committment made by a private organization with respect to its employment practices.

@Jen Ok. Then the question is if this charter is unrelated to the Olympics (i.e. whether the private organisation was asked to make this charter by the Olympic committee or some other other international body or member country involved in the Olympics)? I guess OP should find that and edit the Q accordingly.

It's this one Paris 2024 signed, called "La Charte d’Engagement LGBT+" in French, which is much closer to the English translation you quoted ("LBGT+ Commitment"):

BTW, the EC might not list that one, but French government does. (Apparently said charter was also signed [in Jan 2013] by [former] minister of social affairs and healthcare Marisol Touraine, when she was in office, during the Socialist government.)
Finally, the Diversity Charters that EC lists in that particular directory (that you've linked in the Q) have a much broader scope than LGBT, judging by the French one you've linked to. The articles of that one don't even mention LGBT as such, by the way, but something like:

Favoriser la représentation de la diversité de la société française dans toutes ses différences et ses richesses, les composantes culturelle, ethnique et sociale, au sein des effectifs et à tous les niveaux de responsabilité.

Google translation:

Promote the representation of the diversity of French society in all its differences and riches, the cultural, ethnic and social components, within the workforce and at all levels of responsibility.

So, I can see how LGBT+ rights' advocates would prefer that organizations sign something more specific in that respect. (BTW, the "Charte d’Engagement LGBT+" was launched about 9 years later than the Diversity Charter; 2013 vs 2004.)
